# Payflow update and Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, paypal, url, upgrade

PayPal announcing will have change on URL on Payflow.
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1299

Do I need to do any modification on the Magento side?